# Minimizing paging links in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've struggled with this for quite some time. Today I finally wrote the following code.

The ViewModel contains an `int` property which later tells the view how many pages the data has been split into.

The controller splits the data by taking a specified amount of rows and, in the event of paging, splits by `pageNumber * recordsPerPage`

Take a look:

**The ViewModel**

```
public class ThreadPostsViewModel
{
    public Thread Thread { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
private int PostsPerPage = 10;

public ActionResult Thread(int id, int page = 1)
{
    using (OrtundEntities Db = new OrtundEntities())
    {
        // get the thread and its parent data (parent for breadcrumbs)
        var Thread = Db.Threads.Include(t => t.Title).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        // create a list for the Posts
        List<Post> Posts = new List<Post>();

        // select based on paging
        if (page == 1)
            // no paging has happened, get the first set of records
            Posts = Db.Posts.Include(x => x.User).Where(x => x.ThreadId == id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Take(PostsPerPage).ToList();
        else
            // we're on a new page. Skip however many rows we've already seen
            Posts = Db.Posts.Include(x => x.User).Where( x=> x.ThreadId == id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Take(PostsPerPage).Skip(PostsPerPage * page).ToList();

        // create and return the view model
        ThreadPostsViewModel Model = new ThreadPostsViewModel
        {
            Thread = Thread,
            Posts = Posts,
            Pages = Posts.Count / PostsPerPage
        };

        return View(Model);
    }
}
```

**The View**

```
@model Ortund.Models.ThreadPostsViewModel
<div class="paging">
    @for (int i = 1; i < Model.Pages; i++)
    {
        string Url = String.Format("/View/Thread/{0}?page={1}", Model.Thread.Id, i);

        <a href="@Url">@i</a>
    }
</div>
<div class="posts-list">
    @foreach (var Post in Model.Posts)
    {
        <div class="post" id="@Post.Id">

        </div>
    }
</div>
```

In this code, assuming 300 posts are selected from the database and 10 posts are specified per page, then there should be 30 pages.

Even that's a hefty amount of links to fit into your page design so how can I minimize these paging links and display, say, 10 paging links only where, when you get to say, page 8, the links will change to show you 3-13, for example?

Even having the paging links display as follows would be preferable:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... 90 91 92 93 94
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Mvc.PagedList source code](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) to see how they do it (but note that your current code for `Pages = Posts.Count / PostsPerPage` will return 0 or 1 since `Posts` has a maximum value of `PostsPerPage`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller put value of current page:

```
ViewBag.currentPage = page;
```

In view you can do something like this (not tested):

```
<div class="paging">
@if (Model.Pages > 11 && ViewBag.currentPage > 6)
{
        for (int i = ViewBag.currentPage - 6; i < ViewBag.currentPage -1; i++)
        {
          string Url = String.Format("/View/Thread/{0}?page={1}", Model.Thread.Id, i);
          <a href="@Url">@i</a>
        }
        for (int i = ViewBag.currentPage + 1; i < ViewBag.currentPage + 6; i++)
        {
          string Url = String.Format("/View/Thread/{0}?page={1}", Model.Thread.Id, i);
          <a href="@Url">@i</a>
        }
}
else
{
        for (int i = 1; i < Model.Pages; i++)
        {
          string Url = String.Format("/View/Thread/{0}?page={1}", Model.Thread.Id, i);
          <a href="@Url">@i</a>
        }
}
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but I need to recommend an edit. In the last for, the loop should execute to a fixed amount representing the amount of links you want to appear. In my case I did this so that only 10 links would appear: `for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)`

Comment: Last for loop should execute only if there is 10 or less pages available, so that should not be the problem. Did you test it?